# What version should i put in pom for snapshot exist in Nexus?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, nexus

I have soap-builder snapshot version in nexus.
I declare the version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and tried the numbers appeared in metadata.xml but still unable to fetch artifact from nexus. Please advise. Thank you.

My pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reficio</groupId>
        <artifactId>soap-builder</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

maven-metadata.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
  <groupId>org.reficio</groupId>
  <artifactId>soap-builder</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <versioning>
    <snapshot>
      <timestamp>20150226.115144</timestamp>
      <buildNumber>15</buildNumber>
    </snapshot>
    <lastUpdated>20150226115144</lastUpdated>
    <snapshotVersions>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <value>1.0.0-20150226.115144-15</value>
        <updated>20150226115144</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <extension>pom</extension>
        <value>1.0.0-20150226.115144-15</value>
        <updated>20150226115144</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <classifier>sources</classifier>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <value>1.0.0-20150226.115144-15</value>
        <updated>20150226115144</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <value>1.0.0-20150226.115144-15</value>
        <updated>20150226115144</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
    </snapshotVersions>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Comment: You say: `I declare the version 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT` but you try to use `<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>` . Are you sure you use the correct versions?

Comment: sorry typo. the one in pom.xml is the version i declared. so it is 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Is the repo in Nexus, which contains this library, part of the group you configured in settings.xml?

Comment: Yes in setting.xml the mirror url is set to the group repository,maven-public. And all the repository are added to the group repository in nexus.